# Only in Safari: ReferenceError Can't find variable

Tags: javascript, safari, scope, mobile-safari

Many of my scripts look like this:

```
if (...) {

    const myvariable1 = document.querySelector('.class-1');
    const myvariable2 = document.querySelector('.class-2');

    function someFunction() {

        // Do something with myvariable1 or myvariable2

    }

    someFunction();

}
```

They work fine on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera but on Safari I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable myvariable1
```

**Workaround**

If I declare the constants before the if statement the code works...

```
const myvariable1 = document.querySelector('.class-1');
const myvariable2 = document.querySelector('.class-2');

if (...) {

    function someFunction() {

        // Do something with myvariable1 or myvariable2

    }

    someFunction();

}
```

...but I don't understand why and I don't what to make the constant globally available.

Maybe someone can explain to me that Safari-only-behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This weird behaviour is explained in [Block-level functions in non-strict code - MSN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#block-level_functions_in_non-strict_code).

Enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) will solve this problem.

Comment: Workaround: Instead of `function someFunction() {}` write `var someFunction = function() {}`. This works for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Strict mode is already enabled in jquery and messing with it didn't solved the problem for me in Safari.

Using `var function_name = function_name() {}` work sometimes, but when reloads the error comes back.

The only thing that solved for me is removing the "async" from the load of my js file of functions.

Was

`<script async src="js/header-functions.js"></script>`

Then this solved

`<script src="js/header-functions.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

To me it solved to ensure that function is called once all the DOM elements of the page are ready to be used.

I wrapped script in:

```
    $(function () {
      //do
    });
```